# Checking that all class elements in a list have the same condition

Tags: c#

I have a class `Course` with a `public bool` method `CumLaude` that returns true under certain conditions.
On the `Program` class (different item), I have a `List<Course> gradeList` filled with Course items and a `DisplayGradeList` method which should print "You graduated Cum Laude" only if all Course items in the list have `CumLaude = true`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Does this help you?

```
var allPassed = gradeList.All(x => x.CumLaude());
```